# Custom abbreviation of string vector in R

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to do a custom abbreviation of some strings from a vector `degree_abrev` extracted from data frame `gss`.

This is what I was able to come up with... but I want to see if anybody has a "prettier" way...

```
degree_abrev <- gsub("Lt High School", "LtHS", gss$degree)
degree_abrev <- gsub("High School", "HS", degree_abrev)
degree_abrev <- gsub("Junior College", "JC", degree_abrev)
degree_abrev <- gsub("Bachelor", "B", degree_abrev)
degree_abrev <- gsub("Graduate", "G", degree_abrev)
```

Comment: I'd put these in a table and match/merge on them instead of regexifying (assuming that's possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"plyr" package has "mapvalues" function to do this. I am sure there must be other ways to do this.

```
> degree_abbrev <- c("Lt High School", "High School", "Junior College", 
"Bachelor", "Graduate")

> degree_abbrev
[1] "Lt High School" "High School"    "Junior College" "Bachelor"       
"Graduate"      

> degree_abbrev <- mapvalues(degree_abbrev, from = c("Lt High School", "High 
School", "Junior College", "Bachelor", "Graduate"), to = c("LtHS", "HS", 
"JC", "B", "G"))

> degree_abbrev
[1] "LtHS" "HS"   "JC"   "B"    "G"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is prettier, but I prefer to use sapply.

```
degree_abrev <- c("Lt High School", "High School", "Junior College", "Bachelor", "Graduate")

sapply(strsplit(degree_abrev, " "), function(x){paste(substring(x, 1, 1), collapse = "")})
[1] "LHS" "HS"  "JC"  "B"   "G"
```